# What is an example of implicit declaration in terms of static type binding?

Tags: c++, types

I am currently studying the programming topic of type binding. I understand that type binding is the association between a variable and a type and that there are 2 types of type binding. Static type binding (type binding that occurs during compile time) and Dynamic type binding (type binding that occurs during run time). In addition, static type binding is achieved by 2 methods, the first being explicit declaration (a programming statement used for declaring the types of variables) and implicit declaration. An example of explicit declaration would be as simple as

```
int x; // Variable bounded to int type during compile time
```

However, implicit declaration is much harder for me to grasp. As a result, can anyone post a simple example of code that uses implicit declaration? Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: What is *"implicit declaration"* supposed to mean? That's not a thing in C++.

Comment: Are you sure that these terms were mentioned in connection with C++?

Comment: My mistake everyone. I just found out that some programming languages do not implement static type binding whereas some programming languages do not support dynamic type binding.

Comment: If [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) is what you mean (the type is inferred by the compiler) there's an explanation and examples on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I think C++ don't support implicit declaration so I will assume that you are talking about implicit conversion.

An easy way to ilustrate the implicit conversion might be the next:

```
int x = 1;
double y = x; // 1 will be converted into 1.0 in runtime

string s = '1.2';
double z = (double)s;
double z2 = (double)'aa'; //throws an exception
```

If we were talking about JavaScript, a good example could be:

```
var x; //x has no type yet
x = 1; //type of x will be determinated on runtime
```

I hope It is usefull and help you to understand.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Facundo, but I just had one question about your javaScript example. Would the statement var x; x = 1; be considered implicit declaration? or would this be an example of type inferencing?

Comment: What kind of platform throws an exception when converting a double to an int?

Comment: jajaja, you are right, i did't use a good example because numbers could be converted, in the example it will be truncated!

Answer (score 0):

Older C had some degree of implicit declaration.

If you used a function without an explicit declaration, the compiler was required to act as if you'd declared it a the number and type of parameters based on the number and type of arguments you passed (and if the function definition didn't agree, you got undefined behavior.

Likewise, you could define a function without explicitly declaring its return type (which then implicitly defaulted to `int`).

```
int f() { 
    g(1); //implicitly declared to take an int parameter and return an int
}

g() { return 1; } // return type implicitly declared as int
```

Most of this is now obsolete though. For example, the implicit return type existed in C89/90, but was removed in C99.

C++ has some implicit declarations as well, but they're rather different. For one example, if you create a class in C++, the compiler will usually<sup>1</sup> implicitly declare (for a couple of examples) a default constructor and a copy constructor if you don't explicitly declare a constructor.

```
struct A { 
   int b;
};
```

This has an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator. Most of these (all but the default ctor) take parameters (which are variables) with implicitly bound types.

Note that in this case the implicit declaration is of functions, not variables, so it may be open to question whether this qualifies as exactly what you're trying to discuss or not (but at the very least it's quite similar). As ntoed above, most of the functions take parameters, which are variables that have types that are implicitly defined.

---

1. The implicit declarations sometimes don't happen, such as if the class contains a non-static const member variable, or a variable of reference type.

Comment: Your answer doesn't speak about type binding in declarators (type binding of a variable). You are speaking about "implicit things" in C/C++.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: That's simply not true. Do you not believe that parameters are variables, or did you just miss that part entirely? For that matter, pure functional languages (that don't have variables at all) still have binding. Although the example he gives is of a variable name to a type, the name of a function to a type is a binding as well.

Comment: You are simply right. A function header is also a declarator, and the function name is bind to a function type.

Comment: You could speak about the `auto` specifier, which is also an implicit binding, because you don't say the type of the variable.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: In one of the comments the OP differentiates the implicit binding (that he cares about) from type inference (which he apparently doesn't). `auto` is a clear cut case of type inference (and so are the types of parameters to function templates).